# Bulk modifying html pages

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have the following index.html page, I inserted a div of class "topnav" (see a section with additional hard returns).
Now I need the same code (div of class "topnav") in all other HTML pages in the directory. This could be a few hundreds of files!
I was thinking: "can somebody help me with the creation of a script?" or by pushing a javascript file that can transform all HTML pages in the folder? All the pages have the same header. So we could say: after the first , add a new  and  section with the home/search

```js
function relPathToAbs(sRelPath) {
  var nUpLn, sDir = "",
    sPath = location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]*$/, sRelPath.replace(/(\/|^)(?:\.?\/+)+/g, "$1"));
  for (var nEnd, nStart = 0; nEnd = sPath.indexOf("/../", nStart), nEnd > -1; nStart = nEnd + nUpLn) {
    nUpLn = /^\/(?:\.\.\/)*/.exec(sPath.slice(nEnd))[0].length;
    sDir = (sDir + sPath.substring(nStart, nEnd)).replace(new RegExp("(?:\\\/+[^\\\/]*){0," + ((nUpLn - 1) / 3) + "}$"), "/");
  }
  return sDir + sPath.substr(nStart);
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>


  <title>6129103883 - Schema ST4 styles -- Reference view - do not translate this file. Aperçu de référence - ne pas traduire ce fichier. Referenzansicht - diese Datei nicht übersetzen.</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript"
  />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="generator" content="SCHEMA ST4" />
  <script language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/Common.Core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/Common.Language.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/Production.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Common.Reset.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Core.Production.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/HTML.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="metatable">
      <tr>
        <td class="project">Schema ST4 styles -- Reference view - do not translate this file. Aperçu de référence - ne pas traduire ce fichier. Referenzansicht - diese Datei nicht übersetzen.</td>
      </tr>


      <td>
        <tr>
          <div class="topnav">
            <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
          </div>
      </td>
      </tr>

    </table>





    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="contentLayout">
      <tr>
        <td class="contentLayoutOne">
          <div class="navigation tripletNavigation">
            <div class="tripletHead tripletHeadInfoType"><a href="2729458059.html">Example of Heading 0 (metadata – Installer or User)</a></div>
            <div class="tripletHead tripletHeadInfoType"><a href="9007201984201227.html">Example of Heading 1 (metadata – TitleAcrossAllColumns)</a></div>
            <div class="tripletHead tripletHeadInfoType"><a href="9007201984203403.html">Example of Heading 1 (metadata – TitleAsSectionTitle)</a></div>
            <div class="tripletHead tripletHeadInfoType"><a href="9007201983504779.html">Example of Heading 1</a></div>
            <div class="tripletHead tripletHeadInfoType"><a href="9205593483.html">New Node</a></div>
            <div class="tripletHead tripletHeadInfoType"><a href="9223259787.html">New Node</a></div>
            <div class="tripletHead tripletHeadInfoType"><a href="3529022091.html">Button yes/no</a></div>
            <div class="tripletHead tripletHeadInfoType"><a href="3529617035.html">Button history yes</a></div>
            <div class="tripletHead tripletHeadInfoType"><a href="3529674763.html">Button history no</a></div>
            <div class="tripletHead tripletHeadInfoType"><a href="3529732875.html">Button history</a></div>
            <div class="tripletHead tripletHeadInfoType"><a href="9299784587.html">Topic that contains fragment to link to</a></div>
            <div class="tripletHead tripletHeadInfoType"><a href="9299786507.html">Topic with links</a></div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="contentLayoutTwo"><img src="" /></td>
        <td class="contentLayoutThree">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="titlePageContent"> </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

We inserted of course just the bar at this moment, so we still need a search javascript too to add in the folder structure/HTML pages. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the find and replace functionality in something like Visual Studio Code you can just replace this entire header with the updated one.